# Error in calling cv::stereoBM constructor

Tags: c++, opencv

If I decalre an instance of stereoBM like this

```
cv::StereoBM bmState;
```

the compiler throws the error:

```
cannot declare field ‘bmState’ to be of abstract type ‘cv::StereoBM’
```

But when I declare it like

```
cv::Ptr<cv::StereoBM> bm  = cv::StereoBM::create(16,21);
```

then it works.

Please explain how to go ahead with the former method.

Comment: Some classes require construction through some statically exposed method, you may not have another option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid but you are out of luck, I do not think you can do it. According to https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dba/classcv_1_1StereoBM.html, `StereoBM` is an abstract class, i.e. some of its member function are pure virtual, therefore you cannot instantiate it directly.

Looking at the implementation of `cv::StereoBM::create` https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/stereobm.cpp we can see that in the cpp file a non-abstract derived class of `StereoBM` is defined, namely `StereoBMImpl`. In `create` an instance of it is allocated and returned as a `Ptr<StereoBM>`. Now, I don't think that you can access to `StereoBMImpl` and even if you could, I strongly suggest not to do it, the documentation clearly prescribes a way to use the class and you should stick to it if you want your code to be portable.

Ultimately this is the design you have to accept. If you can tell us why you absolutely need to use the first declaration, maybe we can try to help.

For more info about abstract base classes refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class